# A single word describing a person who is desperate for love/approval, who "comes running" if someone gives the smallest hint of being interested

Tags: single-word-requests

I really hope someone here can help me! I´m looking for an expression, preferably a single word, that describes a person who is desperate for approval/affirmation/love, and who therefore feels compelled to respond positively to every indication of (romantic) interest from other people regardless of whether she/he is really interested herself or not. I´ve been trying to google it but it´s hard knowing what to search for...

Comment: We need to see the sentence you want to put this word into.  Are you looking for a noun or an adjective?  Is a short phrase acceptable?

Comment: Why, please? If English is your first language, try posting your best offering without this magic term.

If your main language isn't English, try posting a direct translation.

Broadly, you seem to be describing some greatly lacking self-confidence/self-worth, but that seems to contradict your specification.

Answer (score 7):

To keep it simple I would call the person

> [**Needy**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/needy)
>
> 2. (of a person) needing emotional support; insecure.

Example sentence: *Greg is so needy that he asks every girl who smiles at him on a date.*

Answer (score 2):

Desperate = Despo! Like a person who tried his or her best to pleased someone, to get accepted, they do weird thing multiple times but they always get rejected, they are always impatient..... this word despo is usually used from Indian people in movies or serial.... " God! Why she/ he is acting like a Despo

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for the new (to me) word. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [guide about answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Normally I am a person of many words, and one would never suffice.. but I am intrigued with trying to answer your question, and entertained with the answers you've received! To my own disappointment the first word that came to my mind was a millennial word, I am definitely not a millennial being over 60, ha, the word I thought of immediately was *thirsty*, LOL.. not one I would advocate for because I do not think it truly covers what you were trying to imply.

I thought long and hard and went back and forth over many words I've known throughout my profession as an editor and an advertising graphics designer so I've had plenty use of being a wordsmith, not proclaiming to be the best but most definitely well versed.. so without further ado the word I came up with is a bit of a rarity and you may even have to look it up to understand it's definition.

The word is **limerence**, the definition is:  a state of infatuation or obsession with another person that involves an all-consuming passion and intrusive thoughts.

That's my 2-cents worth, I would love to know the final sentence, story, essay, writing, etc. when you are through. !

### ~ Happy Pencrafting!**strong text**

- 

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the internet jargon 'simp'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simp

Comment: Hi, Gylos! I've upvoted your answer because I think it is a good fit; and suggest an edit which you may keep or roll back if you like.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps not the best answer but I heard it used in a similar fashion.

**disparate**
2: containing or made up of fundamentally different and often incongruous elements

Comment: You should include the source of the definition.

Comment: Do you mean desperate?  Please explain how this answers the question.  I encourage you to take the [tour] of the site and see the [FAQ] and [help], and welcome.

Answer (score -3):

servile comes to mind, or someone who is a sycophant, or lastly obsequious

Comment: this answer would be much improve you added definitions and why you think those word fit what the OP is looking for.

Comment: All these words (particularly sycophant and obsequious) usually refer to people who'll come running out because they use insincere flattery or the appearance of loyalty deliberately for advancement, not from a desire for love or attention. Merriam-Webster's definition of sycophant includes "self-seeking", while "obsequious" refers to fawning, the first meaning of which is "to court favor by a cringing or flattering manner". Servile isn't quite right either, because there is no sense of reacting to any attention or doing it for approval.